# Debug Perl Segmentation Fault

Tags: perl, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm using [AcePerl](https://github.com/WormBase/AcePerl) to download data from the wormbase.org database.
When I download certain database objects I get (after a certain number of objects) a segmentation fault. This behaviour is reproducible.

I had a look at the core dump and `where` prints a huge stack of function calls:

```
#0  0xb763c0ac in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0xb763eddc in malloc () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x080c07ca in Perl_safesysmalloc ()
#3  0x080f3a02 in Perl_sv_grow ()
#4  0x080ebe38 in Perl_sv_setsv_flags ()
#5  0x080ecb76 in Perl_newSVsv ()
#6  0x0811516f in Perl_save_item ()
#7  0x080c7dd8 in Perl_get_db_sub ()
#8  0x080e7a4c in Perl_pp_entersub ()
#9  0x08075570 in Perl_call_sv ()
#10 0x080edd25 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#11 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#12 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#13 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#14 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#15 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#16 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#17 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#18 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#19 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#20 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#21 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#22 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#23 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#24 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#25 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#26 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#27 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#28 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#29 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#30 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#31 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#32 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#33 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#34 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#35 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#36 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#37 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#38 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#39 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#40 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#41 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#42 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#43 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#44 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#45 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#46 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#47 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#48 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
#49 0x080db6ff in Perl_hv_undef_flags ()
#50 0x080edf72 in Perl_sv_clear ()
#51 0x080ee3eb in Perl_sv_free2 ()
#52 0x080d79ec in Perl_hv_free_ent ()
#53 0x080d7c8c in ?? ()
...
```

These function calls are repeated thousands of time.
I also called `perl -d:Trace myscript.pl > log` but the logfile is about 3 GB large.

Is there a more convenient way to debug this script?

EDIT:
My script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5564630/ .
My schema file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5564631/ . It determines which data to download.
The seg fault is raised after ~2300 `go_terms`.

Comment: Might be worth seeing what's in the stack trace before the loopy bit.

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version of Perl?

Comment: Can you tell me how to extract this stack trace?

Comment: uh, you posted 53 lines of it already... Just curious as to what's on the other end of it.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to extract the stack trace without "the loopy bit". I tried gdb `which perl` -x /tmp/file-containting-the-word--where-- core | tail. But this command takes ages and never finishes.

Comment: The problem is probably that you ran out of stack from endless recursion. I just thought it might be nice to see what started it all.

Comment: It's not a bug in your script (at least directly). It might be a bug in Perl itself, which is why I asked about Perl versions. It could also be a bug in an XS module, which the DB driver you mentioned surely is.

Comment: Perl says: `This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int`. So I should look for another version of the XS module? Maybe I'll try to start a virtual machine with Fendora and see if the error is reproducible.

Comment: What I actually asked was "Have you tried with the latest version of Perl?" That would be 5.16.1

Comment: I tried with Fedora live system and there it works. Thanks ikegami!

Answer (score 6):

Install [Devel::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aTrace).

Run your perl script with tracing enabled:

```
perl -d:Trace myscript.pl >trace 2>&1
```

Tail the file to see which Perl lines are executed leading up to the segmentation fault.